# how to include a "social share" box on my pages using django?

Tags: django

I have a `social.html` template that I can include on my site to add the "social share" box, including Twitter, Gacebook, G+...

The problem is that I want to pass a URL to it (the one to be shared). Sometimes it's not the "current" URL, sometimes I need to include this file more than once (one for each element of the page)

My ideal solution would be something like:

```
{% include 'modulos/social.html' with shareURL={% url soccer %} %}
```

But this `{% %}` inside `{% %}` doesn't work

Any other ideas?

Comment: why not include the just pass shareURL as a variable {{ shareURL }} to the template that includes social.html, since social.html has access to the template tags of its parent template

Answer (score 1):

```
{% url soccer as shareURL %}
{% include 'modulos/social.html' %}
```

That assigns the URL to the variable "shareURL", and as long as you have a "shareURL" variable referenced in the "modulos/social.html" template, it should carry over.